# 1.5A USB Device Design

Tags: usb, usb-c

I seek to design an USB device or UFP, using a USB-C connector and do not wish to use power delivery (PD) of USB-C as my application would be a big underuse of this feature. The device would use a STM32 microcontroller with USB Full Speed (FS) capability which I already found, and the max current would be 1.5A@5V. I seek it to be able to be powered by a varitety of USB ports, including wall chargers. USB is quite a complicated norm, but here's my understanding so far of how the device should be designed:

1. The device would not draw more than 100mA upon connecting.
2. The device would include an IC ([This](https://www.st.com/en/interfaces-and-transceivers/stusbcd01b.html#overview) for example) whose goal would be, in compliance to the USB Battery Charging (BC) norm, to determine if what is powering the board is a dummy wall charger (~DCP) or something more intelligent (SDP), eventually with BC compliance (CDP)
3. If what's powering the board is a DCP, I must assume that it either have the current capability or that (if the user wasn't wise enough and picked a DCP with not enough power) it has current limiting capabilities (that will result in the shutting-off without explosion of the power output) and therefore enable the high current (1.4A) draw of my device.
4. If what's powering the board is an SDP or a CDP, the device would, using the STM32 USB FS capabilities, start the USB communication, enumerate itself and announce its wish to get 1.4A of current, and if accepted by the SDP/CDP enable the high current draw of the device. In the other case, the device would still be able to function (but without exceeding the 100mA limit) and for example could be reprogrammed, communicate data, etc.
5. Both CC pins of the USB-C connector should have Rd pull-down resistors with a value of 5.1kΩ ± 10% so that if a true USB-c DFP is connected, the DFP enables Vbus to +5V and accepts to communicate.
6. I don't know if the other unused pins of the USB-C connector should be connected to ground or left unconnected.
7. I should use an IC for ESD-handling on the D- and D+ line, and also clamp the voltage on Vbus although not mandatory.
8. The device should present a 1.5k pullup resistor on D+ to identify itself as a FS device, although I'm unsure if this should be enabled with the GPIOs of the MCU after the BC IC did its magic, or if it doesn't matter.

Can you confirm my understanding, and if not indicate what I got wrong or forgot ?

I would be very thankful.

Comment: Although I read in many places that the 0.5/0.9A is a minimal maximum, actually it seems that  the USB protocol itself can't ask for more current than the established "maximum" (0.5A for USB 2.0), meaning this maximum is truly a maximum. Therefore the device will never be able to ask for 1.4A using USB 2.0. Therefore what power consumption should the device pretend when establishing USB 2.0 communication with a 1.5/3A capable usb-c or a CDP ? Perhaps it just can't ?